# Node.js pass variable to route

Tags: node.js, express

I have very simple node.js noob question.  How do I pass a variable to an exported route function?

Routes file

```
exports.gettop = function(n, req, res) {
  console.log(n);
  res.send(200);
};
```

Server file

```
app.get('/api/v1/top100', routes.gettop(100));
```

Error: .get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For your example, you want to create a new function that will close around your value of `n`. In your case, you are executing `gettop` and passing the returned value to express as your route, which means `gettop` needs to return the route handler.

```
exports.gettop = function(n){
    return function(req, res) {
        console.log(n);
        res.send(200);
    };
};
```

Answer (score 18):

As your code looks like you're using express you can use express app locals and express result locals to pass variables to your route. While the other answers propose working solutions I think that it's less obtrusive to use express mechanisms to set these variables.

With response locals ([See Express API reference](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.locals)) you first have to set a variable somewhere in a middleware or route. I'll show the middleware approach

```
app.use(function(req,res, next) {
  res.locals.top = 200;
  next();
});
```

then in your route you can access this property via res.locals.variablename

```
exports.gettop = function(req, res) {
  console.log(res.locals.top);
  res.send(200);
};
```

In case you want to make these settings application wide a better approach is to use app locals ([See Express API reference](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.locals))

To set an app locals variable you can use

```
app.locals.top = 100;
```

To access this variable from your route use

```
exports.gettop = function(req, res){
  console.log(req.app.locals.top);
  res.send(200);
};
```

Comment: In that case, I would prefer `app.set(...)` and `[req.]app.get(...)`, since that won't have any side effects (since locals are passed to templates).

Comment: I had to call `next()` inside the middleware function so the page would not hang.

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative to loganfsmyth's (very valid!) solution, you could leave your `gettop` function as-is and create a partial function:

```
app.get('/api/v1/top100', routes.gettop.bind(null, 100));
```

Comment: Strangely, this logic isn't working when the bound function (routes.gettop) is an 'inherited' method (i.e., defined in the object's prototype chain rather than as a method of its own). The handler is actually registered, but it never gets called!

Comment: @LexLythius that it never gets called sounds strange. I can imagine that it gets called with the incorrect context, which in my example is `null` but for a bound method should probably be the instance (`routes`).

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
app.post('/find_user',
   require('./naas/autentication'),
   require('./naas/authorization')(paramForRouter),
   require('./routes/users'));
```

Where

require('./naas/autentication') is for example

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {next();}
```

And require('./naas/authorization')(paramForRouter) is

```
module.exports = function (paramForRouter) {
    return function (req, res, next) {
        this.param = paramForRouter;
        console.log("Param value",this.param);
        next();
    };
};
```

Comment: i like this answer the best, in the start.js using something like: app.post('/api/v1/project/new', new_project(db)); - to pass the database variable into the end-point, and then inside the new_project.js, a function that returns a function like you have